# How to find the width of hidden text on the webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am trying to add this tooltip, which gets resized based on the width of the text it contains. Tooltip is a div and it has another div containing the text.

```
<div><div> tooltip text </div></div>
```

I assign text to it using javascript as mytooltiptext.innerHTML=sometext. The tooltip is hidden with display set to none, and becomes visible on mouse hover. I am trying to set its width before it even becomes visible based on the width of the text/text containing div. But when I try to get the clientWidth or scrollWidth of the text containing div, it comes out as zero. My understanding is that it is happening due to the element being hidden. I tried setting its display to block and visibility to hidden and then tried to get the requisite values, but to no avail. Is there a way to get the width of hidden text without making it visible first?

Comment: It's the default behavior. What is wrong with showing it, getting its width and then hiding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't hide it, move it off screen then bring it back on hover.

CSS:

```
.inputtext span {
margin-left: -999em;
position: absolute;
}

.inputtext:hover span {
position: absolute;
left: 1em;
top: 2em;
z-index: 99;
margin-left: 0;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inputtext">Hover Me<span id="hiddenText">
This is the hidden text and some more text</span></div>​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/PBsJA/3/

Answer (score 0):

You could draw it way offscreen. 
something like:

```
.myCssStyle{
  position: absolute;
  right: 5000px;
}
```